# regular expression for extracting some data from a text file

Tags: java, sql, regex

I have a text with sentences by this format:

```
sentence         1    This is a sentence.
t-extraction     1    This     is       a sentence
s-extraction     1    This_DT    is_V     a_DT sentence_N
sentence         2    ...
```

As you see, the lines are separated by enter key. **sentence**, **t-extraction**, **s-extraction** words are repeated. The numbers are sentence numbers 1,2,.. . The phrases are separated by **Tab** key for example in the first line: `sentence(TAb)1(TAb)This is a sentence.`
or in the second line:`t-extraction(TAb)1(TAb)This(TAb)is(TAb)a sentence.`

I need to map some of these information in a sql table, so I should extract them.
I need first and second sentence(without **sentence** word in first lines and **t-extraction** and **numbers** in second lines). Each separated part by Tab will be mapped in a field in sql (for example `1` in one column, `This is a sentence` in one column, `This` (in second lines) in one column, and also `is`  and `a sentence` ).

What is your suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.split().

The regex you could use is `[^A-Za-z_]+` or `[ \t]+`

Answer (score 0):

Using the split method on String is probably the key to this. The split command breaks a string into parts where the regex matches, returning an array of Strings of the parts between the matches.

You want to match on tab (or \t as it is delimited to). You also want to process three lines as a unit, the code below shows one way of doing this (it does depend on the file being in good format).

Of course you want to use a reader created from your file not a string.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/my/file.data"));
        String line = null;

        for(int i = 0; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; i++){
            if(i % 3 == 0){
                String[] parts = line.split("\t");
                System.out.printf("sentence ==> %s\n", Arrays.toString(parts));
            } else if(i % 3 == 1){
                String[] parts = line.split("\t");
                System.out.printf("t-sentence ==> %s\n", Arrays.toString(parts));
            } else {
                String[] parts = line.split("\t");
                System.out.printf("s-sentence ==> %s\n", Arrays.toString(parts));
            }
        }
    }

}
```